# Why apt-get dselect-upgrade wants to remove certain packages even the selection state is install

Tags: linux, apt-get, dpkg

here is how

```
dpkg -l
```

output looks like (there are some other packages also)

ii  vim        2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1  i IMproved - enhanced vi editor

ii  vim-common 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 Vi IMproved - Common files

As I can see the current state and selection state both is set to install. however when i run command

```
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

it tries to remove Vim (and other packages)

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:

**vim** (with other packages even those packages are not selected for deinstall)

WHY it is doing like this?